# Drools planner: nurse rostering scenario configuration with competition.xsd

Tags: configuration, xsd, schema, drools-planner

I am modelling a personnel rostering based on [Drools Planner Nurse Rostering](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html/useCasesAndExamples.html#d0e1555).

I am toying with the `*.xml` samples based on the `competition.xsd` schema.
The schema is in general very clear, but there are so many configuration parameters that I am not sure how to properly configure each of them. For instance, I cannot figure out how to correctly set up the `patterns` and their usage in the `contracts` tags.

The aim is to correctly model my scenario `.xml` file in order to avoid unnecessary contraints and to correctly weight the useful ones.

So, I am looking for some detailed references about the `competition.xsd` schema, and maybe a tutorial about the usage of the schema.

Comment: Duplicated by [this mailing list post](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Drools-Planner-configuration-schema-td4020446.html)

Comment: @Geoffrey. Maybe you meant [this other post](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Nurse-rostering-configuration-with-competition-xsd-schema-td4020433.html#a4020437) ;). Anyway I am going to close this question. Still I don't mean to remove it, couse I think can be useful for someone.

Comment: Please add comments besides your downvotes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nurse rostering competition documentation found [here](http://www.kuleuven-kulak.be/nrpcompetition).

A usefull article by [Geoffrey De Smet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472109/geoffrey-de-smet) [here](http://blog.athico.com/2010/03/nurse-rostering-design-choices.html).